# Setting user calendar permissions on Exchange 2007

Tags: active-directory, exchange, outlook

We have Exchange 2007 with about 100 users. I would like to change everyone's free/busy permissions to grant Reviewer status to a specific AD group.

I have tried PFDAVAdmin tool but when I commit any changes, they do not affect the users. If I grant myself Reviewer permissions to another user's calendar using the tool, I still cannot view that user's free/busy details, and I also don't show up on the list of people with permissions on that user's Outlook calendar options.

It seems like PFDAVAdmin simply appears to do something, but doesn't actually change anything. Is there any other way for me to accomplish what I need to do? Or is there something I may not be doing right with PFDAVAdmin?

FYI I have followed directions from this link: http://exchangeshare.wordpress.com/2008/05/27/faq-give-calendar-read-permission-on-all-mailboxes-pfdavadmin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I was able to solve my own problem by copying PFDAVAdmin to a different server, running Windows 2003 R2. I tried on a different server with Windows 2008 but it did not work. By doing this, I was able to successfully expand each user and see all their stores, and applying the calendar permissions actually worked!

Comment: Run elevated on 2008 next time.  UAC and all that jazz.